# Navigate one collection view controller to another collection view controller?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I am trying to navigate one collection view controller to another collection view controller,Because I want to show my images one collection view to another collection view by using navigation. Is there any possibility to do that?
Please help me

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate on the problem and show us what you have done so far to achieve the goal?

Comment: I'm sure you can do that, implementation will depend on what model view controller you're using. What language/framework are you trying to set this up in?

Comment: Thank you for replying me, I have posted the answer for that but I don't know how and where to use scroll at item because I want my images showed exact like gallery app. that means my images will scroll based on its position in horizontal scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did by my own... here I am attaching my code 1st I created struct

```
import Foundation
struct City {
    var image:String = ""
    var name:String = ""
    
    init(image: String, name: String){
        self.image = image
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

after that I enter code for my 1st cell view controller

```
import UIKit

    private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"
    
    class cityCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
        var cities : [City] = [ City(image: "Ankara", name: "Ankara"),
                                            City(image: "Antalya", name: "Antalya"),
                                            City(image: "Aydin", name: "Aydin"),
                                            City(image: "Bodrum", name: "Bodrum"),
                                            City(image: "Canakkale", name: "Canakkale"),
                                            City(image: "Cappadocia", name: "Cappadocia"),
                                            City(image: "Efes", name: "Efes"),
                                            City(image: "Eskisehir", name: "Eskisehir"),
                                            City(image: "Fethiye", name: "Fethiye"),
                                            City(image: "Istanbul", name: "Istanbul"),
                                            City(image: "Izmir", name: "Izmir"),
                                            City(image: "Mardin", name: "Mardin"),
                                            City(image: "Nemrut", name: "Nemrut"),
                                            ]
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
    
        }
    
        
    
        // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource
    
        override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
            
            return 1
        }
    
    
        override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            
            return cities.count
        }
    
        override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "dataCell", for: indexPath) as! cityCollectionViewCell
                
                    
            cell.cityImageView.image = UIImage(named: cities[indexPath.row].image )
            cell.cityNameLabel.text = cities[indexPath.row].name
                
                    return cell
        }
        override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                let imageDetailVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "collectCollectionViewController") as! collectCollectionViewController
    
    /
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(imageDetailVC, animated: true)
           
            }

       
        
    
    
    
    }
```

created a data cell and gave the outlets

```
import UIKit

class cityCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var cityImageView: UIImageView!
       @IBOutlet weak var cityNameLabel: UILabel!
    
}
```

This is for my second cell view controller

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class collectCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
    }

   var obj = cityCollectionViewController()
    var app1 = secondCollectionViewCell()
    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        
        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        

        return obj.cities.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Datacell1", for: indexPath) as! secondCollectionViewCell
        let city1 = obj.cities[indexPath.row]
        cell.image11.image = UIImage(named: obj.cities[indexPath.row].image)
        cell.label11.text = obj.cities[indexPath.row].name
        

        return cell
    }


    

}
```

This code for my second data view cell

```
import UIKit

class secondCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var image11: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label11: UILabel!
}
```